# tkinter application structure - using LabelFrames and Class

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-layout

Python-tkinter beginner here...

I would like to fill the main window (MainWin) with 2 vertical labelFrames (ModeWin and StatusWin) using the object oriented approach found here: [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

The code runs but no labelFrames at all :-(

```
import tkinter as tk
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLASS
class ModeWin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg='light blue')
        self.parent = parent
        self.lblFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Mode", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.lblFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self.lblFrame, text="Text in ModeWin")
        self.lblFrame.grid()

class StatusWin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg='light green')
        self.parent = parent
        self.lblFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Status", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.lblFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.label = tk.Label(self.lblFrame, text="Text in StatusWin")
        self.lblFrame.grid()
    
class MainWin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.modeWin = ModeWin(self)
        self.statusWin = StatusWin(self)
        
    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
        
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN
def main():
    app = MainWin()
    app.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Would appreciate your advices on it.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb when inheriting from a frame, all child widgets should be a child of the class itself, not its parent. Otherwise, there's zero advantage of inheriting from the frame class. In other words, make the parent of the label frames `self` rather than `self.parent`.

You then need to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on your classes so that they appear.

Also, you need to either give the label frames a size or put one or more widgets in it. Otherwise, the frames will be 1x1 pixel and virtually impossible to see.

Finally, if you're only putting a single widget in a frame, such as putting the label frames in `self`, it's easiest to use `pack` rather than `grid` since you can get it to fill the frame with a single command and without having to remember to give the rows and columns weight.

Here's your code with all of those changes:

```
import tkinter as tk
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLASS
class ModeWin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg='light blue')
        self.parent = parent
        self.lblFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Mode", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.lblFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.lblFrame, text="Text in ModeWin")
        self.label.pack(side="top")

class StatusWin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,bg='light green')
        self.parent = parent
        self.lblFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Status", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.lblFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.lblFrame, text="Text in StatusWin")
        self.label.pack(side="top")

class MainWin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.modeWin = ModeWin(self)
        self.statusWin = StatusWin(self)

        self.modeWin.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.statusWin.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN
def main():
    app = MainWin()
    app.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: THANK YOU Bryan Oakley for your valuable answer. Your explanations are exactly what I needed.